# How can I use Ruby's to_json in a subclass and include super's json?

Tags: ruby, json

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'json'

class A
  def to_json(*a)
    { :a => 'a' }.to_json(*a)
  end
end

class B < A
  def to_json(*a)
    super({ :b => 'b' })
  end
end

puts B.new.to_json
```

produces

```
{"a":"a"}
```

How do I get it to produce

```
{"a":"a", "b":"b"}
```

in a reasonable way?

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and the latest json gem.

A related question is: what are the arguments *a to to_json?  I've scoured the docs to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two hashes `{:a=>'a'}` and `{:b=>'b'}` in two classes, they're encapsulated i.e. hidden from outside world. The only way I can see is parse the json string into hash and merge them, then convert the result to json.

```
class B < A
  def to_json(*a)
    JSON.parse(super).merge({:b=>'b'}).to_json
  end
end
```

But here will be small difference: you're merging `{:a=>'a',:b=>'b'}` and got the `{"a":"a","b":"b"}`

`*a` is parameter to set options for json format

Comment: "*a is parameter to set options for json format".  I can see that, but what are the legal options?

Comment: honestly, I didn't see any example of using it

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having a different method json_map.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'json'

class A
  def to_json(*a)
    json_map.to_json(*a)
  end

  def json_map
    { :a => 'a' }
  end
end

class B < A
  def json_map
    map = super
    map[:b] = 'b'
    map
  end
end

puts B.new.to_json
```

Maybe there is a more beautiful solution, but this works.