# extending to_json for a subclass of Hash

Tags: ruby, json

I have a subclass of Hash that adds a new field f.  I'd like JSON to serialize and de-serialize f along with the contents of the hash itself, but haven't figured out how to do that:

```
Class ExtendedHash < Hash
  attr_accessor :f
end
```

Of course as written, `ExtendedHash#to_json` does not preserve the the f field:

```
>> c = ExtendedHash[{:a => 1, :b => 2}]
=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}
>> c.f = 123
=> 123
>> c.to_json
=> "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}"
```

So what are the right definitions for:

```
  def to_json(*a)
    ...
  end
  def self.load_from_json(str)
    ...
  end
end
```

?  (I've looked at ['How can I use Ruby's to_json in a subclass and include super's json?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636509/how-can-i-use-rubys-to-json-in-a-subclass-and-include-supers-json) but that doesn't seem like the right approach here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does the right thing:

```
require 'json'

class ExtendedHash<Hash
  attr_accessor :f

  def to_json(*a)
    {
      'json_class' => self.class.name,
      'f' => f,
      'super' => super
    }.to_json(*a)
  end

  def self.json_create(s)
    self[JSON.load(s["super"])].tap {|o| o.f = s["f"]}
  end

end
```

And it works like this:

```
> x = ExtendedHash["a", 1, "b", 2]
=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
> x.f = 123
=> 123
> s = x.to_json
=> "{\"json_class\":\"ExtendedHash\",\"f\":123,\"super\":\"{\\\"a\\\":1,\\\"b\\\":2}\"}"
> y = JSON.load(s)
=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
> y.f
=> 123
```

The only thing that's weird about it is that the underlying hash is "doubly-json'ed" that is, converted to a JSON string and then run through JSON again.  That creates lots of extra escape characters, and requires an explicit call to `JSON.load` in the `json_create()` method.

I can live with that, but maybe there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

can you do this:

```
class ExtendedHash < Hash
  attr_accessor :f

  def to_json(*args)
    Hash[self].merge(:f => f).to_json(*args)
  end
end
```

Comment: Well, maybe.  The f field is intended to be separate from any key-value pair, so the above will fail if the hash already has a key named "f".  I could use an obfuscated key that was unlikely to be used in practice, like `(:i0have0no0life0 => f)`, but that doesn't pass the smell test.

Comment: @fearless_fool You'd still use the same methodology, although if you want it separate from the hash I question that the hash subclass is the right place to put it--I'd compose a new class if your class will be exposing non-hash values.

Comment: @DaveNewton: fair point.  A subclass of Hash feels right in my case, since I want something that does everything that a hash does.  But I have figured out a solution which isn't too bad (elsewhere here).